# How do I make my sections show in the Blogger Layout editor?

Tags: templates, blogger

When I upload my custom XML to Blogger, the code validates, but my `<b:section>`s do not show up in the Layout Editor for adding Widgets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>

    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

    <title>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
        <data:blog.pageTitle/>
        <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;error_page&quot;'>
          <data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/>
          <b:else/>
          Page Not Found | <data:blog.title/>
        </b:if>
      </b:if>
    </title>

    <b:skin>
        <![CDATA[

        ]]>
    </b:skin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <b:section class='header container' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
            <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='' type='Header'></b:widget>
        </b:section>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <b:section class='tabs container' id='crosscol' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='yes'>
            <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='Pages' type='PageList'></b:widget>
        </b:section>
    </nav>

    <div class='container'><div class='row'><!-- start container for page + advertiser -->

    <section id="page" role="main" class='col-md-8'>
        <b:section class='main' id='main' preferred='yes' showaddelement='no'>
            <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'></b:widget>
        </b:section>
    </section>

    <section id="advertisement" role="complimentary" class='col-md-4'>
        <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar-right-1' maxwidgets='' showaddelement='yes'>
            <b:widget id='HTML-1' type='HTML'></b:widget>
        </b:section>
        <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar-right-2' maxwidgets='' showaddelement='yes'>
            <b:widget id='HTML-2' type='HTML'></b:widget>
        </b:section>
    </section>

    </div></div><!-- end container for page + advertiser -->

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <b:section class='footer container' id='footer' maxwidgets='' showaddelement='yes'></b:section>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout page is cached. Try after editing f.e. shift-F5 (in Chrome) to clear the cache.